# How to check if the string characters have equal duplicates

Tags: algorithm

I want to Check if the characters of a string have equal duplicate

if I enter :"abaababb"
returns true because I have 4 'a' and 4 'b' in that string

if I enter : "addda"
returns false because I have 2 'a' and 3 'd'

I tryed to check the duplicates but I found out I have to do it for some characters

Comment: Use a loop to iterate over the string and a map for keeping track of each character's count. Then iterate over the map and check if all counts are equal

Comment: You need a map with the chracter as a key and the count of that character as value for the key, so you need to loop the characters of the string add them to the map and increment the count of that key in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just need to create an empty object and loop through each character and increment the value associated with the key. Keep track of the highest value so we can easily use every on the array from Object.values and check if all character counts match this value

```
let check = "abaababb";
let check2 = "addda";

function hasEqualCharacters( input ) {
  let characters = {};
  let highestCount = 0;
  
  for( let i =0; i < input.length; i++) {
    if( characters[input[i]]) {
      characters[input[i]]++;
      if( highestCount < characters[input[i]]) {
        highestCount = characters[input[i]];
      }
    } else {
      characters[input[i]] = 1;
    }
   }

  
  return Object.values(characters).every( (charCount) => {
    return charCount === highestCount;
  });
}

console.log(hasEqualCharacters(check));
console.log(hasEqualCharacters(check2));
```

Can see it working here
https://playcode.io/1024243